# In k8s code : why should we need the member variable 'storage' in struct GenericAPIServer

Tags: kubernetes

Since we have member 'v1ResourcesStorage' in struct Master, why should we need the member variable 'storage' in struct GenericAPIServer,thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It was ripe for refactoring, and no longer exists in master